# How to modify diagonal of a list element

Tags: r, list, lapply

I'd like to add `toAdd` to the diagonal of every element of list a. How can I do this? I tried

```
diag(a) = lapply(a, function(x) (toAdd + diag(x)))
```

but it doesn't work.

**CODE:**

```
a =list(
  matrix(1:4, 2, 2),
  matrix(5:8, 2, 2))

toAdd = list(
  c(1, 3),
  c(1, 2)
)
```

**DESIRED OUTCOME:**

```
out =list(
    matrix(c(2, 2, 3, 5), 2, 2),
           matrix(c(6, 6, 7, 9), 2, 2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) {diag(y) <- x + diag(y); y}, toAdd, a)
```

Or use

```
Map(function(x, y) `diag<-`(y, diag(y) + x), toAdd, a)
```